# Найти суммарный размер всех регулярных файлов в каталоге, рекурсивно обходя все подкаталоги

Tags: linux, файловая-система

Сама задача следующая: программа получает на вход в аргументах командной строки имя каталога и печатает на стандартный поток вывода суммарный размер (в байтах) всех регулярных файлов в нем. При этом пропускать все записи, являющиеся символическими ссылками.

У меня есть написанная программа, которая успешно выдает какие-то числа, но я не знаю, как убедиться в том, что она выдает правильный ответ. Подскажите, пожалуйста:

1) Можно ли как-то решить исходную задачу средствами bash (команда ls и так далее)?

2) Какие могут быть "крайние" случаи, на которых программу стоит протестировать? Ну кроме пустого каталога.

Comment: Проверить (в данном случае `/tmp`) можно, например, так: `ls -alR  /tmp | grep '^-' | awk '{ sum += $5 } END { print sum }'`

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Calculating a directory size using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392413/calculating-a-directory-size-using-python)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392413/calculating-a-directory-size-using-python

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Чтобы подсчитать *суммарный размер обычных файлов* ([`S_ISREG`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html)) в заданном дереве директорий, пропуская все symlinks, на Питоне:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
from contextlib import suppress

def get_tree_size_scandir(path):
    """Return total size of all regular files in directory tree at *path*."""
    size = 0
    for entry in os.scandir(path):
        with suppress(OSError): # ignore errors for entry & its children
            if entry.is_dir(follow_symlinks=False): # directory
                size += get_tree_size_scandir(entry)
            elif entry.is_file(follow_symlinks=False): # regular file
                size += entry.stat(follow_symlinks=False).st_size
    return size

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    print(get_tree_size_scandir(sys.argv[1]))
```

Пример:

```
$ ./get-tree-size /usr
7217750930
```

Вывод показывает, что общий размер всех обычных файлов в `/usr` директории, около 7 GB.

#### Python, listdir()

Для проверки, я реализовал `get_tree_size()`, не используя `os.scandir()`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import stat
from contextlib import suppress

_dir_flags = os.O_RDONLY

def get_tree_size_listdir_fd(fd):
    """Return total size of all regular files in directory tree at *fd*."""
    size = 0
    for name in os.listdir(fd):
        with suppress(OSError): # ignore errors for entry & its children
            st = os.lstat(name, dir_fd=fd) # don't follow symlinks
            if stat.S_ISDIR(st.st_mode): # directory
                top_fd = os.open(name, _dir_flags, dir_fd=fd)
                try:
                    size += get_tree_size_listdir_fd(top_fd)
                finally:
                    os.close(top_fd)
            elif stat.S_ISREG(st.st_mode): # regular file
                size += st.st_size
    return size

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    print(get_tree_size_listdir_fd(os.open(sys.argv[1], _dir_flags)))
```

*Результаты одинаковые* в данном случае, но в общем случае они могут отличаться (например, `os.listdir()` возвращает список (сразу все имена), а `os.scandir()` возвращает итератор, поэтому `os.scandir()` может учесть больше имен, а `os.listdir()` пропустит всю директорию, если произойдёт ошибка c получением хотя бы одного имени в директории). Код для примеров адаптирован из [Python issue: PEP 471 implementation: os.scandir() directory scanning function](http://bugs.python.org/issue22524).

**Внимание:** *размер файла и занимаемое место на диске могут отличаться*.

#### Bash, du

> 1) Можно ли как-то решить исходную задачу средствами bash (команда ls и так далее)?

Можно, конечно, но результаты могут немного отличаться (см. тестовые случаи). Если нужны точные результаты, то несложно написать программу, с точным необходимым поведением как показывают примеры кода на Питоне выше.

`du -bs .` возвращает значение, которое превышает *суммарные размеры файлов*, например:

```
$ ls -l
total 8
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me me 820 Oct 25 22:59 get_tree_size_fd.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me me 631 Oct 25 23:07 get_tree_size_scandir.py
```

Суммарный размер: `820 + 631 == 1451`:

```
$ python3 get_tree_size_fd.py .
1451
```

что ожидаемо (Питон возвращает правильный результат), но `du` возвращает неверный результат:

```
$ du -bs .
5547    .
```

`-b` опция уже включает в себя `--apparent-size` (то есть результат уже не отражает *занимаемое место на диске* -- как и хотелось).

[@avp упомянул](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/461105/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%85-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5#comment504076_461116):

> du считает также размеры всех каталогов, которые они занимают на диске.

Что подтверждается экспериментами:

```
$ mkdir dir # создаём пустую директорию
$ python3 get_tree_size_fd.py . # результат ожидаемо не изменился
1451
$ du -bs .                       
9643    .
```

Результат для `du` стал больше, что согласуется c [комментарием @avp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/461105/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%85-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5#comment504076_461116).

Если выключить `--apparent-size`, то `du` возвращает *занимаемое место на диске*:

```
$ du -s -B1 .
16384   .
```

Что ещё больше отличается от *суммарного размера файлов*.

> 2) Какие могут быть "крайние" случаи, на которых программу стоит протестировать? Ну кроме пустого каталога.

Потестировать имена файлов, директорий, начинающихся на точку (`.zshrc`, `.ssh`).

Потестировать на директории со специальными файлами, например, `/dev` директория может содержать `/dev/sda` файл, который не является обычным файлом (это диск -- блочное устройство [`S_ISBLK`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html)) или FIFO ([`S_ISFIFO`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html)) (можно создать командой: `mkfifo /tmp/named_pipe`).

Или потестировать на директориях с нечитаемыми записями, например, из-за недостатка прав доступа (командой `chmod` можно подготовить).

И, конечно, потестировать на директориях, содержащих символические ссылки ([`S_ISLNK`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html)), которые ссылаются как на обычные файлы так и на другие директории.

Для проверки надёжности, можно сгенерировать глубоко-вложенные директории с именами записей разной длины, состоящих из произвольных байтов (всё кроме слэша `/` и нулевого байта `'\0'`, если локальная система не вносит своих ограничений).

#### С, nftw()

Для сравнения, можно посмотреть на примеры кода на С/С++. Для рекурсивного обхода дерева директорий, [можно `nftw()` использовать](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nftw.html):

```c
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500
#include <ftw.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  if (argc > 2) {
    fputs("Usage: get-tree-size [<root-dir>]\n", stderr);
    exit(2);
  }
  int flags = FTW_PHYS; // do not follow symlinks
  int nopenfd = 100; // maximum number of directories that nftw() may hold
                     // open  simultaneously
  uintmax_t size = 0;
  int visit_path(const char *fpath, const struct stat *sb,
                 int typeflag, struct FTW *ftwbuf)  // nested function -- gcc extension
  {
    if (typeflag == FTW_F) // regular file
      size += sb->st_size;
    return 0; // continue
  };
  const char *dirpath = (argc == 2) ? argv[1] : "."; // default is the current working directory
  if (nftw(dirpath, visit_path, nopenfd, flags))
    exit(1);
  return printf("%" PRIuMAX "\n", size) < 0;
}
```

Пример: `$ gcc get-tree-size-ftw.c && ./a.out`

Чтобы передать дополнительные переменные (`size`) в `visit_path()` обратный вызов, gcc позволяет использовать вложенные функции.

В общем случае, для более тонкого контроля обхода дерева директорий, к примеру, чтобы пропустить всё внутри `.git` и других подобных директорий, есть [`fts_open()` API](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fts.3.html), добавив [`fnmatch()` API](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fnmatch.3.html), можно реализовать аналог команды:

```
$ find -name .git -prune -o -type f -name \*.txt -print
```

#### С, readdir()

При желании, можно руками с помощью `readdir()` рекурсивный обход директории выполнить:

```c
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <string.h>

static uintmax_t get_tree_size_readdir(int dirfd)
{
  DIR *dirp;
  if (!(dirp = fdopendir(dirfd)))
    return 0; //NOTE: ignore errors from open,openat,fdopendir here
  uintmax_t size = 0;
  for (struct dirent* entry; (entry = readdir(dirp)); ) {
    // skip ".", ".." entries
    size_t namelen = strlen(entry->d_name);
    if (entry->d_name[0] == '.' // 1 <= namelen <= NAME_MAX
        && (namelen == 1 || (entry->d_name[1] == '.' && namelen == 2)))
      continue;
    struct stat statbuf;
    if(fstatat(dirfd, entry->d_name, &statbuf, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW))
      continue; //NOTE: ignore errors
    if (S_ISREG(statbuf.st_mode)) // count size of regular files only
      size += statbuf.st_size;
    else if (S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode)) { // count the size in subdirectories
      int fd = openat(dirfd, entry->d_name, O_RDONLY); 
      size += get_tree_size_readdir(fd); //NOTE: if nested deeply; it may exceed `ulimit -n`
      close(fd);
    }
  }
  //NOTE: ignore readdir() errors
  closedir(dirp); //NOTE: let the caller to invoke rewinddir() if necessary
  return size;
}
```

- директория задаётся с помощью `dirfd` это позволяет избежать каждый раз от корня все пути просматривать, так как `entry->d_name` содержит только последнюю часть пути. В противном случае пришлось бы создавать путь от входной (с которой вызов начался) директории каждый раз, прежде чем путь в `stat()` передать
- специальные имена `"."` и `".."` явно пропускаются
- используется `AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW`, чтобы не следовать по символическим ссылкам, чтобы получить информацию о самой записи (`entry`)
- ошибки по индивидуальным записям явно игнорируются

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  if (argc > 2) {
    fputs("Usage: get-tree-size [<root-dir>]\n", stderr);
    exit(2);
  }
  const char *dirpath = (argc == 2) ? argv[1] : "."; // default is the current working directory
  return printf("%" PRIuMAX "\n", get_tree_size_readdir(open(dirpath, O_RDONLY))) < 0;
}
```

Пример:

```
$ gcc get-tree-size-readdir.c && ./a.out
```

#### С++, <filesystem>

В C++ рекурсивно обойти дерево директорий можно используя [`<filesystem>` библиотеку](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator):

```c++
#include <experimental/filesystem>
#include <system_error>
#include <iostream>

namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  if (argc > 2) {
    std::cerr << "Usage: get-tree-size [<root-dir>]\n";
    std::exit(2);
  }
  uintmax_t size = 0;
  fs::path dirpath = (argc == 2) ? argv[1] : fs::current_path();
  for (auto&& entry : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(
         dirpath, fs::directory_options::skip_permission_denied)) {
    std::error_code ignore_error;
    if (fs::is_regular_file(fs::symlink_status(entry, ignore_error))) {
      size += fs::file_size(entry);
    }
  }
  std::cout << size << '\n';
}
```

- символические ссылки, указывающие как на директории так и на обычные файлы пропускаются
- `"."` и `".."` записи также пропускаются
- ошибки доступа и ошибки при чтении статуса файла игнорируются, но цикл может исключения выбрасывать в случае других ошибок.

Пример: `$ g++ -std=c++11 *.cc -lstdc++fs && ./a.out` (для `<experimental/filesystem>`). В С++17 можно просто `#include <filesystem>` использовать. Библиотека также доступна как `#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libboost-{file,}system-dev  # install Boost on Ubuntu
$ g++ -std=c++11 *.cc -lboost_{file,}system && ./a.out
```

Все варианты кода для подсчёта суммарного размера выдают один и тот же результат в обычных случаях, но возможны отличия, когда исключительные ситуации по разному обрабатываются.

Производительность ограничивается скоростью диска. Если мета-данные уже закэшированы в памяти, то вариант с `<filesystem>` медленнее, чем `nftw()` и `readdir()`, которые похоже себя ведут. `<filesystem>` код только немного медленнее кода на Питоне.

Comment: можно на хабре публиковать. статья шикарная!

Comment: @SeniorPomidor: спасибо за добрые слова. Хабр один из лучших сайтов в рунете по IT, но мой ответ мне кажется слишком техническим  для хабра (отношение код/слова большое -- аудитория, кому это может быть интересно относительно узкая). Хотя не читаю хабр регулярно -- не имею представления какие статьи там приветствуются.

Comment: надо спросить у Итана

Answer (score 1):

```
    du -s /your/path/*
```

Где /your/path/ - путь к папке. Размер указывается в килобайтах.

Если нужно в байтах, то:

```
    du -sb /your/path/*
```

Comment: Могу добавить, что если хочется ещё и посмотреть какой каталог\файл сколько весит, то можно воспользоваться прогой ncdu.

Comment: Тут кроме единиц измерения есть ещё разница: без `-b` `du` выводит занятое место на диске, т.е. с учётом свободной области за концом файла до конца последнего блока отведённого файлу системой и без дырок в разреженных файлах.

Comment: `du -sb /usr` возвращает неверное значение (чуть больше чем надо на моей машине), если сравнить с [кодом на Питоне](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/461144/23044). Возможно, `du` cчитает размер не только регулярных файлов.

Comment: du считает также размеры всех каталогов, которые они занимают на диске.