# Найти файлы по части пути, не только по имени c Python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, python-3.x, файлы, search

Как найти файлы полное имя которых заканчивается на `'*/path/to/folder/myfile.ext'`?

```
files = glob.glob('*/path/to/folder/myfile.ext')
```

Не находит. Работает только по короткому имени файла.

*дополнительно*
как в общем случае найти файл по регулярному выражению полного имени (пути)?

Comment: Здесь в общем случае вам не обойтись без полноценного поиска по дереву каталогов.

Comment: Опишите, какие варианты "кусочков" путей к файлам могут ожидаться на вход?

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev варианты вида "путь/к/папке/полностью/файл*.с.дикими.картами". Папка извесна точно, имя файла по regex

Comment: Не очень понятно в таком случае, что вы имеете в виду. У вас в вопросе такое ощущение, что требуется найти все файлы, путь к которым заканчивается на `/path/to/folder/myfile.ext`. Про какую папку вы говорите, когда сообщаете, что папка известна?

Comment: перефразировал.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`glob()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) *уже* работает с частями путей:

```
import glob

files = glob.glob('*/path/to/folder/myfile.ext')
```

Эта команда найдёт все файлы вида:

```
<текущая рабочая директория>/<любая поддиректория>/path/to/folder/myfile.ext
```

Если хочется найти `path/to/folder/myfile.ext` *в любом месте* дерева директорий, то можно использовать `**` шаблон:

```
files = glob.glob('**/path/to/folder/myfile.ext', recursive=True)
```

`**` должен быть отдельным компонентом пути.

В [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) есть `.glob()` и `.rglob()` методы соответственно:

```
from pathlib import Path

folder = Path("путь/к/папке/полностью")
files_with_maps = folder.glob("имя.файл*.с.подстановочными.символами")
```

---

> как в общем случае найти файл по регулярному выражению полного имени (пути)?

Файловые шаблоны и регулярные выражения это разные вещи, например, если `*.txt` шаблон преобразовать в regex:

```
>>> import fnmatch, re
>>> regex = fnmatch.translate('*.txt') # file pattern to regex
>>> regex
'.*\\.txt\\Z(?ms)'
```

`glob()` работает с шаблонами. Если хочется работать с регулярными выражениями, то самостоятельно придётся генерировать пути, например, используя `os.walk()` [как уже показал @Timofey Bondarev](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/463869/23044):

```
import os
import re

def find_file(topdir, regex):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(topdir):
        for basename in files:
            path = os.path.join(root, basename)
            if re.fullmatch(regex, path[len(topdir):]): 
                return path
```

`len(topdir):` убирает родительскую директорию из пути (вложенные каталоги с `/` начинаются для целей regex).

В данном случае, если ОСь не различает регистры для файловых имён, то регулярное выражение должно это учитывать самостоятельно (`glob()` автоматически это учитывает).

Можно заметно улучшить производительность, если отсеивать директории (`dirs` можно по месту изменять) -- это требует введения ограничений на входные реглярные выражения, чтобы было ясно какая часть к путям директорий относится.

Comment: Да, надо подробнее ознакомиться с нововведениями Python 3.5, отличный ответ

Answer (score 6):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то вот код, который может помочь:

```
import os
from itertools import chain
from fnmatch import fnmatch 


def get_match_filenames(root, pattern):
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
        for filename in chain(files, dirs):
            full_name = os.path.join(path, filename)
            if fnmatch(full_name, pattern):
                yield full_name
```

Здесь с помощью функции [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) обходятся все файлы, находящиеся в каталоге root, подходящие под wildcard, сохранённый в `pattern`.

Проверка на то, подходит ли имя файла под `pattern`, выполняется с помощью функции [`fnmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.fnmatch) встроенного модуля [`fnmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html).

Функция реализована в виде генератора, что позволяет экономить на создании списка и удобно при больших объёмах подходящих файлов.

---

Если требуется находить именно файлы, можно использовать сокращённую версию:

```
import os
from fnmatch import fnmatch 


def get_match_filenames(root, pattern):
    for path, _, files in os.walk(root):
        for filename in files:
            full_name = os.path.join(path, filename)
            if fnmatch(full_name, pattern):
                yield full_name
```

---

В документации к библиотеке `fnmatch` говорится также, что функция [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.filter) работает как код `[n for n in names if fnmatch(n, pattern)]`, но реализована более эффективно, поэтому можно сравнить скорость работы первого варианта с такой реализацией:

```
import os
from itertools import chain
import fnmatch 


def get_match_filenames(root, pattern):
    full_names = (os.path.join(path, filename)
                  for path, dirs, files in os.walk(root)
                  for filename in chain(files, dirs))
    return fnmatch.filter(full_names, pattern)
```

Важно заметить, что здесь возвращается список целиком, и это недостаток такого подхода: при большом количестве результатов их придётся все одновременно держать в памяти, даже если это не требуется в алгоритме работы.

---

#### Пример использования

```
print(list(get_match_filenames('/home/user/docs', '*/src/*.py')))
```

**Обратите внимание**, в этом коде учитывается вид разделителей каталогов: если передаётся `pattern = r'code\*.py'`, то на linux ничего найдено не будет, так как для разделения каталогов используется символ `/`.

Comment: Круто. Работает. Но я чёй-то думал в `python`е это долно быть "из коробки".

Comment: Против `os.walk` выставили [`scandir`](https://github.com/benhoyt/scandir) и говорят он быстрее на порядок. В `python-3.5` это уже `os.scandir`

Comment: Да, хорошее замечание.

Comment: @kyb: не верьте всему, что пишут, например, [код с `os.listdir()` работает не медленнее, а иногда быстрее чем `os.scandir()`](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/461144/23044). То есть всегда измеряйте время исполнения в вашем конкретном случае, если производительность важна.