# Алгоритм работы с файлами на Python: копирование случайно выбранных файлов до достижения предела размера в МБ

Tags: python, алгоритм, файлы, случайные-числа

Есть папка, содержащая несколько тысяч файлов одного типа, но с разными именами и размерами. При запуске программы нужно ввести некоторый размер в МБ (например, 10 МБ). В ходе выполнения программы из исходной папки случайным образом копируются файлы из в указанную папку, пока размер указанной папки не станет больше либо равен введённому ранее значению размера (например, те самые 10 МБ).

Comment: Ну, собственно, как в вопросе написали, ровно так в коде и написать, всё описано грамотно и в код переводится очень легко. В чём конкретно проблемы, которые потребовали создать данный вопрос?

Comment: (хотя есть один нюанс, но он несущественнен и потом обсудится)

Comment: @andreymal в чем именно заключается нюанс?

Comment: @MichaelPak считать ли размер каталога по сумме байтов в файлах или по занятым на ФС кластерам. Ибо если набрать 10 мегабайт файлов по, например, 512 байт, то фактически окажется занято примерно 80 мегабайт, если кластеры по 4 килобайта.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как то так:

```
import os, random, shutil

old_dir = "old/"  # старая директория
new_dir = "new/"  # новая директория
size = 10 * 1024 * 1024  # getsize() возвращает байты
file_list = os.listdir(old_dir)  # список файлов с старой директории

while sum(os.path.getsize(f) for f in os.listdir(new_dir)) < size:
    file = file_list.pop(random.randint(0, len(file_list)))
    shutil.copy(old_dir + file, new_dir + file)
```

Comment: 1- Это не будет работать: `os.listdir()` возвращает относительный путь 2- `L.pop(randint(0, len(L)))` не будет работать так как `len(L)` неправильный индекс. Можно `randrange()` использовать. Или проще `shuffle(L)` один раз вызвать 3- Это `O(n*k)` (квадратичный) алгоритм (`n` - кол-во файлов в старой директории, `k` - кол-во файлов в новой). Его можно улучшить до [`O(n)` линейного алгоритма](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/498385/23044)

Comment: @jfs, во первых, можно просто запустить скрипт из корневой директории. А во вторых: да, твой вариант гораздо производительнее, +1 ;)

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы скопировать случайно-выбранные **.type* файлы из *source* папки в *destination* папку, так чтобы суммарный размер скопированных файлов не превышал заданный в коммандной строке предел в байтах (`limit = 10MiB` по умолчанию):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Usage: copy-random-files [<size-limit-MiB>]"""
import random
import shutil
import sys
from pathlib import Path

MiB = 1024 * 1024
limit = (int(sys.argv[1]) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 10) * MiB
size = 0
paths = list(Path("source").glob("*.type"))
random.shuffle(paths)
for path in paths:
    size += path.stat().st_size
    if size > limit:
        break
    shutil.copy(str(path), str(Path("destination") / path.name))
```

- Чтобы все записи из папки без разбору взять, можно использовать [`Path("source").iterdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.iterdir) вместо [`Path("source").glob("*.type")`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob)
- [`random.shuffle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) перемешивает пути в случайном порядке
- размер папки считается по сумме размеров файлов, которые она содержит в данном случае. Фактически занимаемое место на диске может отличаться. См. [Найти суммарный размер всех регулярных файлов в каталоге, рекурсивно обходя все подкаталоги](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/461105/23044)

Это алгоритм является [`O(n)`](https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/) линейным по памяти и времени, где `n` -- это общее кол-во `*.type` в `source` папке.

Comment: «`set()` гарантирует случайный порядок при каждом запуске программы» — не уверен, что хорошо так нагло привязываться  конкретной реализации — PyPy3 у меня перемешивает каждый раз одинаково (хотя ещё и модуля pathlib в нём не обнаружил, но это другая история)

Comment: @andreymal: pypy хорошо поддерживает чистый Python 2 код. Поддержка Питона 3, который мой ответ явно использует в нём плохая. Это проблема Pypy (мой код не использует детали реализации CPython). Легко можно написать ответ, который будет как  на Питоне 2 так и 3 работать (например, используя `random.shuffle()`). Назначение кода быть *исполняемым псевдо-кодом* в этом случае (достаточно что он читаем и работает на стандартном Питоне).

Comment: Для «исполняемого псевдокода» это тем более плохо.) Как и применение `<<`.

Comment: 1- *"это тем более плохо"* -- что Вы имеете ввиду -- по пунктам. 2- *"Как и применение <<"* -- поэтому `10MiB` рядом указано для новичков (для опытных разработчиков `1 << 20` и так читаемо).

Comment: Я имею в виду, что если уж писать псевдокод, а не production-ready сверхшуструю версию, то надо писать его максимально понятно и очевидно

Comment: @andreymal: я поэтому и спросил *"что Вы имеете ввиду"*: что именно не ясно и не очевидно (по вашему мнению). Не общие слова, а конкретно (строка/выражение).

Comment: Указано в первом и третьем комментарии. И вами же объяснена причина неочевидности в четвёртом.)

Comment: @andreymal: я ничего конкретного кроме единственного замечания про  *"Как и применение <<"* не вижу. В программе 7 строк, если импорты исключить. Какая строка вызывает у вас затруднение в понимании?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36374/discussion-between-andreymal-and-jfs).

Comment: @andreymal: решил учесть ваши замечания: хуже код от этого не  стал, а для некоторых людей может быть более читаемым.