# Посчитать размер файлов, созданных 21 июля

Tags: ubuntu, grep, redhat

Есть папка в `/Archive` - там 10000 файлов, надо найти все файлы созданные 21 июля и посчитать их сумму.

```
$ ls -l | grep -c "Jul 21"
```

Как это можно сделать?

---

так не работает:

```
$ for i in ls -l | grep "Jul 21" | awk '{print $NF}'; do AB=0; AB=du -sh $i | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/K//g' | cut -d. -f 1; SUM=expr $AB + $SUM ; done
```

Comment: for i in `ls -l  | grep  "Jul 21" | awk '{print $NF}'`; do  AB=0; AB=`du -sh $i | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/K//g' | cut -d. -f 1`; SUM=`expr $AB + $SUM` ; done  не работает

Answer (score 1):

найти файлы, созданные 21 июля 2016-го года можно, например, так:

```
$ find /archive -newerct 2016-07-21 \! -newerct 2016-07-22
```

подсчитать же общий их размер можно, например, с помощью программы *du*. примерно так:

```
$ find /archive -newerct 2016-07-21 \! -newerct 2016-07-22 -print0 | xargs -0 du -ch | tail -n 1
```

Comment: спасибо, сработало. Просил двух индусов из саппорта - оба дали неправильные комманды. Если бы не вы то не сносить бы мне головы.

Comment: @Kwaker: 1- вы не получите суммарный размер файлов, если `du -с` больше одного раза вызывается (что возможно если `find` печатает много имён файлов) 2- Дата создания на Linux не всегда доступна (`newerct` использует дату последней модификации метаданных файла, что может отличаться). ext2/3 не хранят дату создания, ext4 файловая система хранит, но специальное API может быть нужно. Посмотрите на Birth time в выводе `stat filename`, а не Change time, используемое `newerct` 3- [Существует разница между местом, занимаемым на диске и отображаемым размером](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/461105/23044)

Answer (score 0):

find . -name "*20160725*" -print -exec du -ks {} \; | cut -f1 | awk '{total=total+$1}END{print total/1024}'