# Задача в получении метаданных списка файлов из установленной директории с помощью сторонней утилиты(exiftool)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вопрос в переборе листа файлов с целью последующей обработки.

```
###
import os
import sys
from subprocess import Popen
#
path = "d:/test"
def dir_ask ():
    print ("path:",'\n')
    direc = input(dir)
    if direc == "d:/test":
        print("normal")
    else:
        os.chdir(path)
        print ("incorrect")
        print ("repaired")
    print(path)
    return
#
def file_list():
    list = os.listdir(path)
    print (list)
    return list
#
def get_atr():
    cmd = 'exiftool.exe -k -a -u -g1 -w txt'
    i = 0
    for i in list:
        i = i + 1
        p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell = true)
    pr = str(p.stdout.readlines())
    print (pr)
    return
#
dir_ask()
file_list()
get_atr()
```

Я пытаюсь задать путь папки с файлами, это  + Я прошу получить список файлов,  + Я пытаюсь применить запуск КОМАНДНОЙ СТРОКИ с вызовом СТОРОННЕЙ программы, для КАЖДОГО из файлов в СПИСКЕ. Вот применение сторонней программы к элементам в списке не происходит. Компилятор ругается на синтаксич.ошибку описания СПИСКА.

Comment: А почему бы не воспользоваться [PIL (Pillow для Python 3)](https://gist.github.com/erans/983821)?

Comment: Словами опишите что вы ожидали код должен делать и что вместо этого происходит. Не используйте сломанный код в качестве спецификации задачи. [mcve]

Comment: [пример чтения вывода exiftool в Питоне](http://askubuntu.com/a/761710/3712) и  [получения метаданных (размера файлов) в дереве диреторий](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/461144/23044)

Comment: Я пытаюсь задать путь папки с файлами, это +
Я прошу получить список файлов, +
Я пытаюсь применить запуск КОМАНДНОЙ СТРОКИ с вызовом СТОРОННЕЙ программы, для КАЖДОГО из файлов в СПИСКЕ. Вот применение сторонней программы к элементам в списке не происходит. Компилятор ругается на синтаксич.ошибку описания СПИСКА.

Comment: откуда в процедуре `get_atr` возьмётся `list` если это _зарезервированное слово_ и такая переменная у вас является локальной для процедуры `file_list`?

Comment: @Eugene_Venev не помещайте информацию необходимую для ответа в комментарии, отредактируйте ваш вопрос. Нажмите [edit]

Comment: Приведите явно traceback, чтобы было ясно где ошибка происходит.  Попробуйте одну задачу за раз решать. К примеру, если проблема с вызовом внешней команды, то уберите весь код, который напрямую к запуску команды не относится, создайте минимальный пример кода, который проблему показывает [mcve]