# Как узнать размер ТОЛЬКО файлов в папке linux?

Tags: linux

Я перепробовал множество команд, но не получается вывести только файлы (не папки). Нужно отсортировать файлы <100 байт, <1 Кб, <10 Кб и тд. Использовал команду `-du -sh *`, но она показывает файлы И папки.
Благодарю за ответы! (:

Comment: Привидите пожалуйста пример данных, и как должен выглядеть желаемый результат.

Comment: В директории 2 файла, которые меньше 100 байт. Результат должен выглядеть: '<100 bite: ##'  *где решётка- один файл меньше 100 байт*

Comment: Связанный вопрос [Найти суммарный размер всех регулярных файлов в каталоге, рекурсивно обходя все подкаталоги](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/461105/23044)

Comment: Старайтесь ограничиваться одной проблемой на вопрос, отражённой в заголовке (чтобы вопрос был: "как сделать X", а не "напишите приложение, которое делает A,B,C" -- второе гораздо менее полезно для будущих посетителей). Если необходимо, задайте несколько вопросов.

Comment: Буду это учитывать в дальнейшем!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь утилитой **find**. Она довольно универсальна. У неё есть оператор `-size` как раз для выяснения размера файлов. Например,

- `find каталог -type f -size -100c` рекурсивно выводит имена всех регулярных файлов размером строго меньше 100 байт,
- `find каталог -type f -size -1k` также выводит файлы, чей размер меньше 1 КиБ.

Минус перед цифрами означает «меньше».

---

У этой программы есть ещё довольно любопытный оператор `-printf`, позволяющий выводить разнообразную информацию о файле. Как пример,

- `find каталог -type f -printf '%p %s\n' | column -t` выведет на терминал размеры файлов в байтах.

Подробнее со списком параметров можно ознакомиться в руководстве [find(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/find.1.html).

Comment: А возможно избежать поиск файлов в других каталогах? После первой команды на выводе огромный список файлов скрытых каталогов

Comment: Можно. Добавьте опцию `-maxdepth 1` сразу после имени каталога

Comment: Огромное спасибо!! (:

Comment: А как только в скрытых исключить, а не уровнями?

Comment: @Qwertiy, скрытые файлы — это те, чьё имя начинается с точки. Чтобы их отсечь, можно использовать такие операторы: `-not -name '.*'`. (Одинарные кавычки нужны, чтобы оболочка не интерпретировала звёздочку особым образом, а передала бы этот аргумент утилите **find** как есть.)

Comment: @Qwertiy, перечитал ваш комментарий ещё раз. Возможно, не так вас понял. Если хочется исключить поиск в скрытых каталогах, то можно так, например, `-not -path '*/.*/*'`. В этом случае, если в качестве начальных папок не были заданы скрытые, то из выдачи будут исключены все файлы, в пути которых есть скрытый каталог.