# Узнать все подпапки в указанной директории рекурсия

Tags: php, рекурсия, файловая-система

есть скрипт он показывает, что показано в определенной директории, а как сделать так чтобы он возвращал подпапки , иначе те папки которые вложены в папку.

```
1
 ../2
 ../3
    ../4
    ../4
2
../A
```

вот мой скрипт

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];//получаем url без домена
$variable = parse_url($url);//массив ссылки с результами
$address = $variable['path'];// убираем гет ссылку точнее все то что после "?" и получаем только путь 
$path = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].$address;

 $dir = opendir($path);
         while($file = readdir($dir)) {        
          if (is_dir($path.$file) && $file != '.' && $file != '..' && $file != 'js' && $file != 'img') {
                echo "<span>".$file."\n"."</span>";

   }
}
```

Comment: Добавьте к вопросу: пример входных данных(реальную структуру) и пример выходных с понятным описанием

Comment: @ Vyacheslav Potseluyko  папка у меня на сервере

Comment: структуру папки и что должно выйти. Из вопроса не понятно

Comment: связанный вопрос [Найти суммарный размер всех регулярных файлов в каталоге, рекурсивно обходя все подкаталоги](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/461105/23044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если только папки, то можно так

```
recdir('../');


function recdir($dir, $tab = '') {
    $d = opendir($dir);
    $space = str_repeat('&nbsp;', 4);

    while ($name = readdir($d)) {
        if ($name == '.' || $name == '..') continue;
        $temp = $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $name;

        if (is_dir($temp)) {
            echo $tab .'[<b>'. $name .'</b>]<br />';
            recdir($temp, $tab . $space);
        }
    }

    closedir($d);
}
```

А если с файлами в папках, тогда так

```
recdir('../');


function recdir($dir, $tab = '') {
    $d = opendir($dir);
    $space = str_repeat('&nbsp;', 4);

    while ($name = readdir($d)) {
        if ($name == '.' || $name == '..') continue;
        $temp = $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $name;

        if (is_dir($temp)) {
            echo $tab .'[<b>'. $name .'</b>]<br />';
            recdir($temp, $tab . $space);
        } else {
            echo $tab . $name .'<br />';
        }
    }

    closedir($d);
}
```

Comment: @Vadim Запостил ответ.

Comment: а можете объяснить, а как составлять такие алгоритмы, я всю ночь пытался, но постоянно тупил , могу скинуть мой кусок, но если не трудно, то можете объяснить заранее спасибо

Comment: @Vadim можно и описать, но честно говоря, нет столько свободного времени.

Comment: @Vadim чтобы легче вам было понимать алгоритм, пропишите контрольные точки в теле функции. "Контрольная точка" - это обычная встроенная отладочная функция `var_dump();`. С её помощью вы будете визуально отслеживать движение по алгоритму в каждой строке. Например, вам понятно что происходит в этой строке : $d = opendir($dir); ? Думаю, да, а значит контрольная точка для неё не нужна. Дальше идёт строка : $space = str_repeat('&nbsp;', 4); Если не понятно, что она возвращает, то пропишите под ней: var_dump($space); и запустите скрипт. По такой аналогии действуйте и с остальными строками. Успехов!)