# Можно ли в python узнать размер папки, не перебирая каждый файл в ней?

Tags: python

У меня есть метод, который считает размер файлов в папке, но из-за большого количества файлов, скрипт провисает на долгое время. Можно ли сделать тоже самое, только как-то быстрее?

```
def get_size_file_in_direct(path):
  size = 0
  for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
    for f in filenames:
        fp = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
        size += os.path.getsize(fp)
  return size
```

Comment: случайно оставил, смотрел файлы принтом). Но все равно, папка может весить пару терабайт и подсчитывать по байтам не очень как-то

Comment: почему по байтам то. у вас же там не 2 миллиарда файлов.

Comment: как раз может быть и 2 миллиарда, большие проекты по 20 гб минимум

Comment: Нельзя и в этом виноват не питон

Comment: ну 1 гб может быть и одним файлом. вопрос лишь в количестве файлов. А ответ очень простой: быстрее невозможно. потому как со стороны ОС есть только функции получающие имена без размера и `stat` дающая информацию о файле, включая размер.

Comment: Связанный вопрос [Найти суммарный размер всех регулярных файлов в каталоге, рекурсивно обходя все подкаталоги](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/461105/23044) сколько времени занимают решения из этого вопроса?

Comment: @Артур, самый быстрый способ - показать сколько осталось места на диске. Сколько было нужно зафиксировать. Не точно, куча допусков, но как вариант допустим.

Comment: @Igor а как это поможет размер папки узнать? Вы предлагаете удалить папку, чтобы узнать сколько свободного места без неё? (чтобы формулу применить: `размер_папки = свободное_место_без_папки -  свободное_место_с_папкой`)

Comment: @jfs, как правило подобные данные складируются на отдельном жестком диске. Под папкой обычно понимают папку проекта, а не отдельно взятую, точность не всегда нужна. Перед копированием на жесткий диск смотрим свободное место, допустим 5гб, после копирования осталось 3гб. Данные фиксируем перед операцией увеличивающей размер, удалять не нужно. размер = Свободное до - свободное после.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно попробовать воспользоваться win32com, частью pywin32:

```
import win32com.client as com


fso = com.Dispatch("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
folder = fso.GetFolder(path)
mb=1024*1024.0
print  "{}".format(folder.Size/mb)
```

Это быстрее для связки python 2.7 32 bit и Windows 7 c NTFS
Для папки размером 26119 МБ получилось 29.4949 секунд методом win32com и 32.6300 секунд методом обхода, для директории размером 79296 МБ получилось 297.5150 и 354.1380 соответственно.

Comment: А на основании чего вы решили, что данное приложение должно работать именно под windows ? И что то я сомневаюсь что оно будет сильно быстрее, потому что в основе лежат те же системные вызовы

Comment: У меня ругается на строку с folder.Size: `pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Ошибка.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146828218), None)
`, путь указан как 'C:/Windows', зато folder.DateCreated возвращает значение и не ругается. Наверное для того чтобы узнать размер папки Windows нужно от админа питон вызывать, ибо с другой папкой проблем не было

Comment: @Mike Частное решение лучшу чем никакое. Немного быстрее все же быстрее.

Comment: @gil9red Я проверял на папке на с размером 20ГБ -- работает нормально, но я  от админа запускал. На директории Windows я, пожалуй, воздерьжусь от проверок.

Comment: @nick_gabpe: *"Немного быстрее все же быстрее."* -- с чем вы скорость сравнивали? Если [`get_tree_size_scandir(r"c:\some\dir")`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/461144/23044) вызвать (для случаев [cold/warm file system cache](https://stackoverflow.com/q/478340/4279)), то какие результаты получаете по сравнению с `folder.Size`? (совпадают ли числа? какая производительность?) Пробовали из под обычного пользователя запустить ваш код (к примеру, для папки "Мои документы")?

Comment: @jfs : Измерения проводились после рестарта ОС, так что надобности в очистке не было. Я попробовал на двух разных директориях. Код для обхода взял [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1392549/3545745) . Для папки размером 26119 МБ получилось 29.4949 мой метод и 32.6300 секунд методом обхода, для директории размером 79296 МБ получилось 297.5150 и 354.1380 соответственно. Пробовал из под админа Windows, в Моих документах не пробовал. То есть получается, что все же немного быстрее. Скрипты запускал из консоли.

Comment: @nick_gabpe эту информацию можно в сам ответ добавить. Упомяните версии Питона, Windows, название файловой системы. Не могли вы ещё get_tree_size_scandir() на тех же директориях попробовать (совпадают ли размеры, какое относительное время). Если warm cache (когда несколько раз запускали), то как время изменяется?

Comment: @jfs Попробовал get_tree_size_scandir() , но он падает с ошибкой, у меня 2.7. При warm cache ~1 секунды и  ~8.5 секунд для  79296 МБ. Данные совпадают.

Comment: У скрипта явный shebang на python3 указывает. Если бы он поддерживал бы оба Питон 2 и 3, то shebang показывал бы python. Если только Питон 2, то python2. См. [Should I put #! (shebang) in Python scripts, and what form should it take?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31954823/4279)

Comment: Если не секрет, почему вы на Windows используете python 2.7? На Unix можно понять — там он часто уже стоит по умолчанию.  На Windows вы руками ставите и можно несколько поставить версий (py утилита выберет нужный, по опциям в настройках/командной строке. Shebang и на Windows распознаётся).

Comment: На любой Windows приходилось ставить 2.7 так что, по сути,  вторая версия стоит везде, а вот третья версия стоит мало где и с ней много мороки из-за того, что многие библиотеки которые жизненно необходимы с ней несовместимы.

Comment: @nick_gabpe: 1- о "везде стоит": посмотрите на [статистику от PyCharm (доля Питон 3 сравнима с Питон 2. Питон 2 стабильно уступает позиции Питону 3)](https://twitter.com/vlasovskikh/status/801720613312364544) 2-
  О "многих" и "жизненно необходимых" библиотеках: подавляющая часть самых популярных пакетов поддерживают Питон 3 http://py3readiness.org/

Comment: @jfs  я пишу про локальные проблемы: локально везде стоит 2 версия, есть самописные либы, которые никак не получается перевести на тройку. Да, я понимаю, что переходить надо, но... Не сейчас :)