# Поиск файлов по маске

Tags: c, ubuntu

Есть рекурсивная функция обхода директорий и файлов в них. Как сделать поиск файлов по маске, чтобы маска задавалась аргументом при запуске программы и находила нужные файлы в пройденых директория?

Comment: "Есть рекурсивная функция" - а где она есть?

Comment: В чём у вас вопрос состоит? "Как передать аргумент в программу?"(`argv`) "Как файлы обойти в дереве директорий?" ([`nftw()`, `fts_open()`, `readdir()`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/461144/23044)). "Как определить, что имя файла маске соответствует?" ([`fnmatch()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fnmatch.3.html), strcmp(), [`regexec()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43884046/4279) Какие файлы "нужные" у вас? (время создания, тип, размер, итд) Почему именно на Си хотите сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Передать параметр - не проблема. Самый простой способ - оно само прилетает в main.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  if (argc == 1) { // у нас один аргумент!
    puts(argv[1]); // распечатаем его.
   //  в argv[0] обычно хранится путь бинарю
  }
```

Вторая задача - это проверить, что файл соответствует маске. Но можно задачу "развернуть" - искать только те файлы, которые соответствуют маске - для этого поможет функция [glob](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html). В результате задача упрощается - рекурсия нужна только для того, что бы бегать по каталогам, а список файлов внутри каталога поможет найти glob.

Comment: А как в glob задать каталог, в котором искать, ведь в нем нет параметра про директорию, или я что-то упустил

Comment: первым параметром, вместо с маской. По умолчанию - текущий каталог. А дальше либо абсолютный, либо относительный путь.