# Низкоуровневое получение списка каталогов и файлов

Tags: windows

Собственно, вопрос, а можно ли получить список файлов и каталогов на еще более низком уровне, чем через WinAPI функции и тем самым на порядок повысить скорость?

Имеется диск, где 5 ТБ занято и необходимо получить перечень каталогов и количественную статистику по типам файлов.

Пробовал использовать стандартный подход через C# классы и получил результат обхода в 30-40 минут. Можно конечно через голый WinAPI попробовать, но сомневаюсь, что результат будет быстрее. Параллелизм, как я понимаю особо не повлияет на скорость обхода, да и , как я понимаю, вреден.

Вроде, есть MFT таблица, где хранятся все данные. Однако, можно ли до нее достучаться из кода?

Comment: "как я понимаю" - как?

Comment: @Igor, много читал, что параллелизм на IO операции не оказывает никакого позитивного эффекта.

Comment: тут ответов нет https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21661798/how-do-we-access-mft-through-c-sharp ?

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, эти метаданные NTFS спрятаны от WinAPI. Значит надо написать собственный драйвер для чтения MFT-файла и его обработки.А надо ли?

Comment: у меня гораздо быстрее несколько TB пробегаются. Сколько времени [код на Питоне с os.scandir() у вас работает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/461144/23044)? Вот [пример построения дерева директорий, используя потоки (Gtk, Python)](https://askubuntu.com/a/183315/3712)

Comment: @Daemon-5 да нет, вроде не запрятаны, на чтение по крайней мере. Есть даже  .Net библиотека для этого: https://sourceforge.net/projects/ntfsreader/

Comment: @VadimTagil, да. За шустро отработала за 10 минут. Правда, жрет она 4 ГБ ОЗУ.

Answer (score 0):

Вот в таких случаях, когда скорость обхода иерархии упирается в IO, пользуются простым трюком: загружают только верхний уровень иерархии, а пока пользователь работает с этим уровнем - подгружают нижние. И тут параллелизм как раз помогает решить задачу (поток для UI + поток для IO).

Продумайте свою аналитику таким образом, чтобы ее можно было показать пользователю в реальном времени. И по ходу анализа иерархии FS - обновляйте эти результаты в UI.

Вредно как раз рассчитывать на то, что ваше ПО синхронно справится с любым диском за адекватное для пользователя время.

Comment: а с чего вы взяли, что суть в показе иерархии пользователю? мб задача тупо записать дерево каталогов куда нибудь в файл или базу.

Comment: @teran, суть ответа - показать, где используется параллелизм в таких задачах. Возможно, автору вопроса это поможет посмотреть на проблему под другим углом. Он же ждет 30-40 минут, т.е. в конце есть какой-то результат, который ему нужен. Вполне возможно, что ждать столько времени и не надо, и есть возможность задействовать промежуточный результат. Я бы даже 10 минут не ждал, мы не в то время живем.