# C++ Корневая (текущая) папка программы (указать)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, файлы, файловая-система

С++ Как задать корневую (текущую) папку для программы, 
например у меня есть параграмма с файлами картинками (ресурсы программы), но если я откраиваю файл с помощью этой параграммы, программа не находит своих файлов (ресурсов).
в итоге
Корневая (текущая) директория устанавливается в папке с открытым файлом. 
А если я просто открываю программу Корневая (текущая) директория устанавливается в папке с программой, и все ресурсы загружаются отлично.

Использую visual studio 2010
ОС: windows 10 x86

Ответ что я ожыдал
функцыя устанавлевает корневую папку SetCurrentDirectory("Путь к корневой папке програмы");

Comment: Практически везде в вызове `int main(int argc, char*argv[])` значение `argv[0]` - имя файла выполняемой программы. Вытащите из него каталог, в котором находится программа...

Comment: А ОС какая у вас?

Comment: 2 windows. 1 int main(int argc, char*argv[]) не вариант, у меня библиотека которая принимает фал с кодом который интерпретируется, в этом же коде прописываютса относительные пути. мне нужна функция которая задаст папку программы один раз как основную.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Рабочий каталог](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3) используется для поиска файлов, заданных с помощью *относительного [пути](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BA_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%83)*.

Текущая директория наследуется программой от её родителя. К примеру, если запустить в командной строке, то по умолчанию программа будет искать файлы относительно текущего пути в командной строчке (`pwd`, `echo %cd%`).

Если вы запускаете программу вне папки с картинками, то в настройках передайте необходимый путь (в конфигурационном файле, в переменных окружения, в опциях командной строки) и используйте *абсолютные пути* для открытия файлов (переданный путь + относительный путь). Вот [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/461144/23044), где используется либо путь, заданный в командной строке, либо текущий путь, если не задан путь:

```
fs::path dirpath = (argc == 2) ? argv[1] : fs::current_path();
```

Чтобы объединить переданный путь и относительный путь: [`path = dirpath / relpath`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/operator_slash).

Выражение "корневая директория" не имеет отношения к текущей директории (к примеру, [`chroot(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chroot.2.html) vs. [`chdir(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html)).

Comment: В примере питон, а у меня С++ж

Comment: fs::path dirpath = (argc == 2) ? argv[1] : fs::current_path(); Эта строка вызывает ошибки, что такое fs? файловая система что ли.

Comment: @ЮрійПисанка: по ссылке ответ прокрутите до примера на C++. Там полный рабочий пример. Будет ясно, что такое fs. Можно просто current_path поискать на странице.

Comment: У меня нету библиотеки #include <experimental/filesystem>
в visual studio 2010

Comment: это не стандартная библиотека?

Comment: Я ответил на свой вопрос перекодируйте мой ответ в новый свой, чтобы я мог отметить его как ответ.

Comment: @ЮрійПисанка по ссылке явно указаны несколько вариантов как filesystem использовать (и в стандартной  библиотеке и вне, если не доступно) Прочтите ответ по ссылке (ищите filesystem на странице). Кстати, изменять текущую директорию внутри  программы не стоит (если вы точно не знаете зачем), лучше явно пути определять, чтобы было яснее что-откуда берётся при чтении кода, в сообщениях об ошибках, чтобы не путаться. Именно поэтому мой ответ содержит `dirpath / relpath` вместо `fs::current_path(dirpath)`

Comment: Не могу я скачать эту библиотеку Filesystem library на их странице даже скачать кнопки(ссылки) нету. а если это часть набора bost то это гиблое дело, bost два или три раза пытаться скомпилировать и внедрить в IDE и ничего с этого на вышло  лучше буду решать проблемы с входными аргументами (int argc, char*argv[]) при перенастройке проекта в безконсольный для glut glew openGL.

Comment: @ЮрійПисанка если у вас не древний компилятор, boost здесь не нужен. Если не можете в вашем окружении filesystem библиотекой воспользоваться, то задайте отдельный Stack Overflow вопрос, специально об этом: явно упомяните вашу операционную систему, компилятор.

Answer (score 0):

вот пришёл к такому решению
благодаря ан пользователю jfs сумел правильно сформулировать поисковый запрос

еще такой парадокс на заметку: когда я в настройках проекта -> компонировщик - дополнительно устанавливаю точку входа "main" аргумент argc ведет себя странно и принимает некоректное значение, и и массив argv становится пустым что приводит к ошибке при запуске.

проект создаётся как пустой;

функция SetCurrentDirectory("путь"); устанавливает текучкою директорию.

```
#include<string>
#include<Windows.h>
using namespace std;

void main(int argc, char*argv[])
{

    //Получить текущую деректорию
    //TCHAR buffer[MAX_PATH];
    //GetCurrentDirectory(sizeof(buffer),buffer);
    //cout << buffer << endl;


    if(argc > 0)
    {
    //получаим путь к програме
    string urlK = ""; 
    urlK += argv[0];
    //удаляем всё до слеша (название програмы)
    while(urlK.size() > 0) { bool br = 0;if(urlK[urlK.size()-1] == '/' || urlK[urlK.size()-1] == '\\'){br = 1;}
    urlK.erase(urlK.size()-1); if(br)break; }
    //устанавливаем путь к кааталогу с прорамой как основной
    SetCurrentDirectory(urlK.c_str());
    }
return;
}
```

Вот пример где устранена ошибка которою я описывал выше.

```
#include<Windows.h>
#include<string>
//=======================
//Отримати місцезнаходження програми
char* SvcInstall()
{
    TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];

    if( !GetModuleFileName( NULL, szPath, MAX_PATH ) )
    {
        return "error";
    }

    return szPath;
}

//Отримати місцезнаходження програми і задати папку як кореневу
std::string SetDIR()
{
        //получаим путь к програме
    std::string urlK = "";
    urlK += SvcInstall(); 
    //удаляем всё до слеша (название програмы)
    while(urlK.size() > 0) { bool br = 0;if(urlK[urlK.size()-1] == '/' || urlK[urlK.size()-1] == '\\'){br = 1;}
    urlK.erase(urlK.size()-1); if(br)break; }
    //устанавливаем путь к кааталогу с прорамой как основной
    SetCurrentDirectory(urlK.c_str());

    return urlK;
}

int main()
{
// функцыя возвращает путь к папке с програмой, и автоматичиски устанавлевает ее ка текущую
SetDIR();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Тот момент когда нашел свой вопрос и ответ и он вновь помог. Только уже работаю в codeblocks