# Как использовать неполный путь к файлам c++

Tags: c++, qt, виджет, ресурсы

У меня есть приложение, в котором нужно подгружать переводы из файлов и иконки для кнопок. Если я использую полный путь к файлам - они загружаются и используются.

`qtLanguageTranslator.load(QString("D:/C_Projects/grapick/Translations/QtLanguage_en.qm"));`

Но если положить их в папку с проектом или в папку с исполняемыми файлами и в программе задать только их название - программа их не находит.

```
qtLanguageTranslator.load(QString("QtLanguage_en.qm"));
```

Попробовал варианты из интернета - что-то не работает, а что то не получается вытащить из `main.cpp` (мне они нужны в `mainwindow.cpp`).

Подскажите как мне использовать неполные путь к фалам, чтобы эта программа работала на других пк (где пути установки программы разные).

Этот вариант не сработал: [C++ Корневая (текущая) папка программы (указать)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/758013/c-%d0%9a%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c) (или я не понял как его использовать)

Comment: Вы говорите что ложили фалы в директорию с запускаемой прогой - а запускали то ее откуда?

Comment: Из qt запускал.

Comment: вы понимаете что это вообще ничем не говорит? Из какой директории запускается программа?

Comment: Из D:\C_Projects\build-grapick-Desktop_Qt_5_13_1_MinGW_32_bit-Release\release Но и там файлы не всегда программа находит

Comment: а путь к загружаемым файлам? И путь который вы выставили в коде

Comment: путь к фалам использую, например Translations/QtLanguage_en.qm, в 32bit сборке получилось, в 64bit нет. Может это быть из-за того что 64bit установлен в режим debug?

Comment: файлы перевода теперь находит, не находит иконки для comboBox (расположены в папке icons/img.jpg)

Comment: вы понимаете что пути который вы приводите ничего никому (кроме вас) не говорят? В любом случае относительные пути должны указываться относительно директории запуска - не можете определить ее в ide, запусайте из консоли

Comment: а так (файл должен лежать рядом с exe-файлом): `qtLanguageTranslator.load(QString("./QtLanguage_en.qm"));`

Comment: Я положил их в выходную папку проекта и получилось