# Не могу получить размер директории Qt c++

Tags: c++, qt

cur_file.size() возвращает 0, почему?

```
void MainWindow::setDirectory(){
QString directory_way = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(0, "Choose directory: ", "");
QFile cur_file(directory_way);
QFile fileOut("fileout.txt");
if(fileOut.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text))
{
        QTextStream writeStream(&fileOut);
        writeStream << "You chose directory: " << directory_way <<" with size " << cur_file.size();
        fileOut.close();
}}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Размер папки в Qt](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/759576/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-qt)

Comment: связанный вопрос [Найти суммарный размер всех регулярных файлов в каталоге, рекурсивно обходя все подкаталоги](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/461105/23044) (решения на Питоне, bash, Си, C++)

Answer (score 2):

Для Qt нет функции, которая определяла бы размер *папки*. В данном случае подходит лишь перебор файлов, которые находятся в папке, и вычисление их общего веса. Вы можете воспользоваться моим кодом:

```
quint32 listFolder ( QString path ) {
    QDir currentFolder( path );

    quint32 totalsize = 0;                      

    currentFolder.setFilter( QDir::Dirs | QDir::Files | QDir::NoSymLinks );
    currentFolder.setSorting( QDir::Name ); 

    QFileInfoList folderitems( currentFolder.entryInfoList() );

    foreach ( QFileInfo i, folderitems ) {
        QString iname( i.fileName() );
        if ( iname == "." || iname == ".." || iname.isEmpty() )
            continue;

        if ( i.isDir() )
            totalsize += listFolder( path+"/"+iname );
        else
            totalsize += i.size();
    }
    return totalsize;
}
```