# Размер папки в Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Как узнать размер папки используя Qt?

Answer (score 1):

Вот так:

```
quint32 listFolder ( QString path ) {
    QDir currentFolder( path );

    quint32 totalsize = 0;                      

    currentFolder.setFilter( QDir::Dirs | QDir::Files | QDir::NoSymLinks );
    currentFolder.setSorting( QDir::Name ); 

    QFileInfoList folderitems( currentFolder.entryInfoList() );

    foreach ( QFileInfo i, folderitems ) {
        QString iname( i.fileName() );
        if ( iname == "." || iname == ".." || iname.isEmpty() )
            continue;

        if ( i.isDir() )
            totalsize += listFolder( path+"/"+iname );
        else
            totalsize += i.size();
    }
    return totalsize;
}
```

Comment: Добрый день. Без многопоточности проект падает , видимо из-за больших вычислений. Можете помочь организовать создание потока в функции под подсчет каждого каталога?