# Как получить содержимое директории?

Tags: c, unix

Программа по выдаче содержимого каталога. Код компилируется, но содержимого каталога так и не выдает. В чем проблема?

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    DIR *mydir;
    struct dirent *myfile;
    struct stat mystat;

    char buf[512];
    mydir = opendir(argv[1]);
    while((myfile = readdir(mydir)) != NULL)
    {
        sprintf(buf, "%s/%s", argv[1], myfile->d_name);
        stat(buf, &mystat);
        printf("%zu",mystat.st_size);
        printf(" %s\n", myfile->d_name);
    }
    closedir(mydir);
}
```

Comment: Берете отладчик и смотрите где проблема. Может, opendir не сработала...

Comment: УМВР, да и с виду всё правильно... ищи глупую ошибку: забыл пересобрать, запускаешь не то/не так или ещё что...

Comment: Всё выводится, если правильный каталог в аргументах указать. В отладчик идите.

Comment: вызов каждой функции на ошибки следует проверять. Для примера посмотрите как [`get_tree_size_readdir()`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/461105/23044) реализована, которая обходит дерево директорий и суммирует размер обычных файлов  (даже если ошибки игнорируются, это явно делается, чтобы можно было без падений продолжить)

Answer (score 1):

Я бы модифицировал программу так:

```
mydir = opendir(argv[1]);
if (mydir == NULL) {
    printf("Невозможно открыть каталог %s\n", argv[1]);
    return -1;
}
```

И Вам сразу всё станет понятно. Настоятельно рекомендую в 100% случаев **проверять** код завершения, возвращаемый функцией. Касательно функций, возвращающих значение типа *указатель* это правило следует использовать в 200%... Такой стиль программирования отличает программиста, пишущего код программ, которые должны работать надёжно, а не код очередной лабы.