# Посчитать размер файлов

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

Объясните пожалуйста
Надо посчитать размер всех файлов в подпапке, которая находится в главной папке, при этом не считать сам размер подпапки
А вводить надо путь главной папки
В главной папки всего 4 подпапки
На экран должен выводится размер каждой подпапки отдельно
Пытался что-то придумать с `os.path.getsize(path)` не вышло, решил потом вернусь, а время уже поджимает, можете помочь?

Comment: Что значит не вышло? `os.path.getsize` отлично работает, берите и используйте его. Для рекурсивного обхода всех подпапок есть `os.walk`, берите и используйте его тоже, они оба работают, я гарантирую это

Comment: связанный вопрос [Найти суммарный размер всех регулярных файлов в каталоге, рекурсивно обходя все подкаталоги](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/461105/23044)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте:

```
import os
from os.path import getsize, join

# '.' это поиск в текущей папке
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    total_size = sum(getsize(join(root, name)) for name in files)
    print(root, total_size)
```

---

- `root` – это текущая папка на текущей итерации
- `dirs` – список папок в root
- `files` – список файлов в root
- `join(root, name)` – объединяет путь от текущей папке к файлу в ней
- `getsize` вернет размер файла в байтах

---

**Хочу уточнить, что скрипт показывает размер файлов в папке, но не подсчитывает размер папки с учетом других папок.**

Поэтому, если нужно подсчитать размер папки с учетом вложенных папок, можно попробовать этот вариант:

```
# Словарь нужен чтобы помнить размер папки. Когда итератор дойдет до родительской папки
# в словаре уже будут размер вложенных папок
dir_sizes = dict()

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.', topdown=False):
    size = sum(getsize(join(root, f)) for f in files)
    size += sum(dir_sizes[join(root, d)] for d in dirs)
    dir_sizes[root] = size
    
for path, total_size in sorted(dir_sizes.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]):
    print(path, sizeof_fmt(total_size))
```

Параметр `topdown=False` говорит что перебор нужно делать не с корневой папки, а наоборот – с самого низа.

---

Если нужно размер в человеко-читаемом формате показать, можно воспользоваться функцией:

```
def sizeof_fmt(num):
    for x in ['bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB']:
        if num < 1024.0:
            return "%3.1f %s" % (num, x)

        num /= 1024.0

    return "%3.1f %s" % (num, 'TB')
```

И вызвать так:

```
...
print(root, sizeof_fmt(total_size))
```

Comment: Да, работает. Подало только из-за наличия ссылок.

Comment: Тут можно и try/catch, и с аргументами walk followlinks и onerror поиграться